# Python module variable as central storage for data sharing and access in within threads

Tags: python, multithreading, algorithm, ros

In my current algorithm, I am doing some interaction with a robot. The robot is running a ROS master, which publishes all the datas itself. My computer, where the algorithm is running, is connected to the ROS master and controls the robot.

The calculations of the algorithm is based on the current state of the robot (which will be published over ROS). For this case, it is necessary, always having the current state of the robot. However, simultaneously, my algorithm needs to make decisions based on the current robot state continuously. Because I need to do some stuff in parallel, I thought about using threads.

**My idea was the following**

I have a central storage (basically a python module) "vars", which only contains different kind of variables, among others the current robot state. My idea is, to update these variables from ROS so I always have up-to-date data in these variables and I can do my calculations based on this central stored variables.

**My question**

- What do you think about my basic structure?
- Is it safe, to use python module variables within threads?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I would use a blackboard class to share information between threads

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to build a system like you suggested. As long as it's small you shouldn't have any problems, but you should reconsider if you want something that works in larger environments or for longer runs.

The main problems I've seen with designs like this:

- Clutter. There's always that one variable that doesn't have a good name and you want to use it in two modules. In this setup it ends up in the `vars` module making it harder to understand.
- Ownership. In this setup any module can change any variable. If you need to debug then it can get really hard to figure out who did the change and why.
- Hard to test. When you write tests (and you probably should write some) then you need to setup this entire large module which can get tricky.

As improvements, I would suggest not to store values, store classes that own them and are responsible for them. You can extract interfaces if it makes it easier, but you always know which module is responsible for what. This also helps when adding strange variables with imperfect names, since at least you have the module name to give you some hint of what it's for.

For testing it helps if you don't take the entire module, but only the data you need. You can have a tiny wrapper that takes the module, extracts the needed values and passes them to more testable methods.

Also take care of the global interpreter lock in python (GIL). You may not get the parallelism you expect.

Again, all this makes sense when you have a somewhat larger setup or one that you want to keep around for longer. For prototypes and experiments the setup you proposed should work just fine.